# Question regarding List.contains check and on pass set flag using vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I have list of string and i want to check all the value present in datatable, if that present in datatable result set to true.

```vb
Dim resultTestCase As Boolean
Dim values As New List(Of String) From {"Test1", "Test2", "Test3", "Test4", "Test5"}
For i As Integer = 0 To dt.Rows.Count - 1
    If values.Contains(dt.Rows(i)(0)) Then
        resultTestCase = True
    Else
        resultTestCase = False
    End If
Next
```

it set false if datatable has more than 5 value

Comment: Just want to check what you are trying to achieve here. If the DataTable has values that are not in the list what value should the `resultTestCase` be? Can it have the values multiple times?

Comment: Hello @theduck My Senario is - if datatable contains all 5 values from list then execute perticular code, if not then show message that Missing value is not present in datatable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could convert your rows to another list of strings and then you can compare them in different ways for example:

```vb
Dim rowValues = dt.AsEnumerable().Select(Function(row) row(0).ToString())
```

This gives you a List of Strings for each value in the DataRows.

You can then use this to determine if every DataRow value is contained in the test list:

```vb
resultTestCase = rows.All(Function(rowValue) values.Contains(rowValue))
```

You can also check that all the values in the test list exist in the DataTable using:

```vb
resultTestCase = values.All(Function(value) rows.Contains(value))
```

So, your final code would look like this:

```vb
Dim values As New List(Of String) From {"Test1", "Test2", "Test3", "Test4", "Test5"}
Dim rowValues = dt.AsEnumerable().Select(Function(row) row(0).ToString())
Dim resultTestCase = values.All(Function(value) rows.Contains(value))
```

Comment: My Senario is - if datatable contains all 5 values from list then execute particular code, if not then show message that one of value is not present in datatable.

Comment: Sorry not sure I understand. What do you mean help with the vb.net code?

Comment: Sorry i am new to the coding and facing issue while applying this changes in vb.net

Comment: Have added a complete section of code to the answer to try and help.